# jQuery Colorbox for WP doesn't group images

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using jQuery Colorbox Plugin for my website and I wanted to group some pictures with it. My code is as follows:

```
<div class="gal">
    <a class="group cboxElement" href="[img]"><img src="[img]" class="postImg colorbox-manual"></a>
    <a class="group cboxElement" style="display: none" href="[img]"><img src="[img]" class="postImg colorbox-manual"></a>
    <a class="group cboxElement" style="display: none" href="[img]"><img src="[img]" class="postImg colorbox-manual"></a>
    <a class="group cboxElement" style="display: none" href="[img]"><img src="[img]" class="postImg colorbox-manual"></a>
</div>
```

First image is meant to be visible while the rest should remain hidden. My problem is, when I click on the first link, there is no group, no other images to go to.

What can I do?

Comment: But are you using the plugin jQuery standalone or the WP version? Link? Also, what markup is expected apart the rendered? Any errors on the console?

Comment: Wordpress plugin, no errors. Markup seems good, only problem is lack of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I launch it:

```
$('.group1').colorbox({
  opacity:0.9,
  maxWidth:'95%',
  maxHeight:'100%',
  rel:'group1'});
```

Hope it helps!